# How to test a cache lock in python

Tags: python, django, python-unittest, django-tests

I have a django application. Where I am doing following:

```
def important_fun()
   lock = cache.lock('some_string')
   if lock.acquire():
       if var is None:
           critical_function(a,b,c)
       lock.release()
   else:
     log('not acquired')

def critical_function(a,b,c)
  #Do critical stuff
  #var = some_val
```

Now I want to test that if i call important function multiple times in parallel and test if critical_function is called only once (`assert_called_once`)

I tried creating multiple process and threads it didnt work

Comment: In a unit test you would test if the lock is **used** properly by mocking it. You do not test if the actual locking works. That would be out of the scope of the unit and part of the testing of that module or higher level tests.

Comment: Can you please direct me how to test if lock is used properly when multiple request in coming then it would be really helpful

Comment: You **don't** test with multiple parallel requests. Again: it's not the purpose of a unit test to test the lock.